# Entity Framework linq Null values Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

this is my linq query in below code some variable having null values so this linq quert is not working when all 6 variable is presented then its working fine how to solve it please someone help me friends. . .

```
   public JsonResult ItemMaster(string ItemName, string Brand, string Color, string Dimen, string Size, string Char)
    {
        var item = entity.TblItemMasters.FirstorDefault(x => x.ItemName == ItemName && x.BrandName == Brand && x.Color == Color && x.Dimensions == Dimen && x.Size == Size && x.Charecterstitics == Char);
        if (item == null)
        {
                 //do something
         }
         else{
               item.ItemCode
         }
    }
```

Comment: What do u mean by not working, what o/p is that giving?

Comment: its working but it doesn't getting the data from the database for example itemname is Null this query is not getting data from the database

Comment: so thats normal behaviour, if u pass null. only entries with null value will be selectd

Comment: But it not selecting a null value from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be you want

```
  public JsonResult ItemMaster(string ItemName, string Brand, string Color, string Dimen, string Size, string Char)
        {
    var data = from x in entity.TblItemMasters
        where (ItemName == null || x.ItemName == ItemName)
            && (Brand == null || x.BrandName == Brand )
            && (Dimen == null || x.Dimensions == Dimen)
            && (Size == null || x.Size == Size )
            && (Char== null || x.Charecterstitics == Char)
        select x;

    if(data.Count() == 0)
     var Item=data.FirstOrDefault();


}
```

Comment: Ya i tried this method too its also not working. . . because of the data having "Enumeration yielded no results" like this

Comment: @Dinesh Please do not edit other people's answers to change their code. Explain why you think it's wrong in the comments section, and let the author fix it. Somehow, your edit proposal got accepted, but in the future don't do this.

Comment: ok friend sorry friend i can understand i change one small mistake only ok sorry friend